# Which screenDensity specified for Galaxy S8/S8+

Tags: android, google-play

As the title question, I have problem with filter device Galaxy S8/S8+ install my app in Playstore that support screensize normal and above. My manifest for that filtering is:

```
<compatible-screens>
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />

        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />

        <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="213" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="420" /><!--nexus 5X, included 424 for z3 and 428 for z5-->
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" /><!-- xxhdpi -->
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="560" /><!-- xxxhdpi -->
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="640" /><!-- xxxhdpi -->

        <!--<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="567" />--><!--Samsung S8-->
        <!--<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="529" />--><!--Samsung S8+-->
    </compatible-screens>
```

I was believed that xlarge 480 and 560 is enough for filter S8/S8+ from theirs densities are 567 and 529, but it doesn't work.

Any guys got knowledge about this?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the manual

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_560

`This is not a density that applications should target, instead relying on the system to scale their DENSITY_XXXHIGH assets for them.`

That is, `xxxhdpi`.